# two buttons resize to webpage

Tags: html, css

Using only CSS/HTML, I would like for the left half of my page to be a button that directs users to one website (www.knowfitness.net), and the right half to direct to another (for now www.google.com until I get the other site up).. It needs to be able to scale as well. I originally attempted a site map, so that's why the picture is split in half. I'll eventually swap out the images, but for now this one can just be resized. I've been having trouble more specifically with resizing the second image that is supposed to be aligned next to the first.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style>
#outer {
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
display:table;
}
#leftcontainer {

float:left;
display:table-cell;
border:5px;
width:50%;
}
#rightcontainer {

float: right;
display:table-cell;
border:5px;
width:50%;
}
    </style>
    </head>



 <body>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="leftcontainer"><a href="http://www.KnowFitness.net/About"><img src=        "http://knowfitness.net/Direct/DirectoryPage1MB.jpg"/></a>

    </div>

<div id="rightcontainer"><a href="http://www.Google.com"><img src= "http://knowfitness.net/Direct/DirectoryPage1MB.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues. Button tags need to be closed, so replace `<button />` with `<button></button>`. Remove the `position: absolute` from the `#outer`, `remove position: relative` from #button1 and #button2. Remove `right:0px;` from #button2. Add `float: left;` to #button2. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b58qf/

Comment: Thanks, it's damn close, but isn't vertically filling the screen. Any idea why? Even when I set an absolute height for #outer it appears as a small sliver at the the top..

Comment: I can't really debug that since the images are password protected. But, I'm thinking that a big problem has to do with the tags you're using. If you used an <a> tag wrapped around an image, it would probably be much easier to get working the way you want.

Comment: I took your advice, and this seems to be working much better, except now the images are too large for the browser.  Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you dump what you have in a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/? It'll help me debug and help you with your issue.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to mention I updated the code above, but here is your fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/8Kjq8/   Thanks again for the help.

Comment: OK, I removed the `display: table` and `display: table-cell` stuff from the CSS. It wasn't necessary. I also removed the `width: 100%` from `#outer`. Divs are block level elements by default, so it already has a width of 100%. I set the images to `display: block` and gave them a width of 100%. I hope this is working the way you want it. http://jsfiddle.net/8Kjq8/2/

Answer (score 0):

just like the first button you need to make the second button `float: left` to make it align next to each other and `right:0px;` is not necessary